# How do I make so that every person has a different channel (real time chat app)

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, chat

So I set up a chat-app with socket.io. Problem is that when I write something everyone can see it who uses the app. I also made a friends system where you can make friend requestes. What I want now to have is that u have different channels(like WhatsApp & co.) where messages written to person x only are shown to person x and vice versa based on the friends system. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket.IO Best way to send messages between two users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392848/socket-io-best-way-to-send-messages-between-two-users)

Comment: you need to create a chat room and only the participants in the room will be able to listen/broadcast to a channel

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages directly to unique user id.
It's documented here:
https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-socket-instance/#Socket-id